# DataSet.ReadXml - How to catch "input string was not in a correct format"

Tags: c#, .net, xml, dataset

I am reading in some data from XML files using `DataSet.ReadXML()`

My call looks like this (where `XmlFileName` is a `string` w/ a path to an XML File):

```
this.dataSet.ReadXml(XmlFileName, XmlReadMode.InferTypedSchema);
```

This code previously used `XmlReadMode.Auto`, however we were encountering issues with the way it was treating the datatypes. We have been using InferTypedSchema successfully for a few weeks now. Recently we have faced a couple problems.

I boiled down the issue to this: we have a field in our XML file called "Product_UPC"

[image].

This field always (hopefully) contains numbers. We just received a value in this field with a trailing space at the end, so it was something like **"123456 "**

`ReadXml()` with `InferTypedSchema` parameter doesn't like this, and threw an exception internally that `"The input string was not in a correct format"`.

[image]

I assume that since prior "Product_UPC" values were interpreted as numeric earlier in the XML file, .NET is now converting all future values for the same field into numbers too.

Since the error `"The input string was not in a correct format"` can be thrown for any number of reasons, I can't assume the problem is with the UPC itself, nor would I know what exact value in the XML file has an issue to report back to the user. These files end up being 10,000+ lines so it's not exactly possible to ask the user to do a scan for trailing spaces.

Any help or ideas would be great.

Comment: Publish a schema (.xsd) and validate against it before creating DataSet. This will allow you to verify that the data in the xml file is in the correct format before ever attempting to load it into a DataSet. This also has the potential to give you a list of issues to report back to the user.

Comment: It look like you may have a space after 123456.  Did you save xml with embedded schema?  Did you check the schema to see if type was string or integer?  You can add schema to xml as follows : ds.WriteXml(fileName, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use System.Xml.Linq.XElement and repository pattern.You can make Position class same as position tag in xml file.You can read the file and fill the Position objetc or list.  A simple example

```
    class Position { }
class Repository
{
    private XElement xlmRecords;
    public Repository(string filePath)
    {
        xlmRecords = XElement.Load(filePath);
    }
    public List<Position> FindAll()
    {
        return xlmRecords.Elements("position")
            .Select(position =>
            {
                return new Position
                {
                    //You fill the Position properties view xml position values
                };
            }).ToList();
    }
}
```